# Django Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.), solve without @csrf_exempt

Tags: django, csrf

I am getting this error when I call a route in localhost for my django app, http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/calculator/score/. This POST route sends data to a Flask app hosted on aws, and gets back a "score" from there.

The route works if I have the decorator @csrf_exempt, but that seems like a bandaid/temporary/bad solution. However, this is the solution that most other similar posts on Stack Overflow suggest.

How do I allow the request to process without using @csrf_exempt?

I have listed the route in my settings.py like:

```
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
    '<<my flask/amazon url here>>',
    "http://127.0.0.1:8000", 
    "http://localhost:8000"
]
```

and here is the code for the route in views.py:

```
def post_for_score(request): 
    body_unicode = request.body.decode('utf-8')
    body_dict = json.loads(body_unicode)

    flask_url = '<<my flask/amazon url here>>'
    res = requests.post(flask_url, json=body_dict)
    if res.status_code == 200:
        rj = res.json()
        print("rj: ", rj)
        return JsonResponse( rj ) 
    else:
        return JsonResponse({ "error": str(res.content) })
```

Again, this works with the @csrf_exempt decorator, but I don't want to use that, as it seems unsafe in production. What are other ways to fix the problem?

Comment: How do you call this route?

Comment: urls.py: urlpatterns = [
    path('score/', post_for_score, name='post_for_score')
]

Comment: That's the path definition. How do you send a POST request to it? From where? Is it a form on a page? Does the form has the correct CSRF tokens? You did not share the starting point where the request originates.

Comment: The request that hits this "score" endpoint in django originates from a React page, not a django form. Do I need to add something to the incoming JSON object from React?

Comment: Yes, you need to [set the `X-CSRFToken` header](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/csrf/#using-csrf-protection-with-ajax).

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to attach the CSRF token as a cookie in the header with `@method_decorator(ensure_csrf_cookie)`.  Here is a snippet of code I use to reattach it:

```
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views.decorators.csrf import ensure_csrf_cookie


# Empty resonse that sends the CSRF token as a cookie
class CsrfTokenView(APIView):
@method_decorator(ensure_csrf_cookie)
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs) -> Response:
    print('csrf: ', request.META["CSRF_COOKIE"])
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

Comment: I added a similar decorator to my function-based view, like ``` @ensure_csrf_cookie def post_for_score(request): body_unicode = request.body.decode('utf-8') body_dict = json.loads(body_unicode) print('csrf cookie: ', request.META["CSRF_COOKIE"]) ``` but I am still getting the same error. Thoughts?

Comment: Do you have control of the Flask app?  The app needs to send it back.  If you can't change it then I think you are stuck with `@csrf_exempt` and will have to verify the source another way.  Here is a link to the documentation if you have not checked it out:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/csrf/

Comment: So, the Flask needs to attach an x-csrftoken header?

Comment: The issue occurs when django tries to talk to Flask, not when it tries to talk to React

Comment: The issue does not occur when I a similar POST request to the deployed flask endpoint from Postman. So, it's a Django problem. Ideas?

Answer (score -1):

In my case, it was something really silly.. From my "front-end" add an extra "/" at the end of the route.

My log in the console:

```
Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /medical_consultation/8/delete/
```

BAD

```
const request = await util.axios(token).delete(`/medical_consultation/${id}/delete/`);
```

GOOD

```
const request = await util.axios(token).delete(`/medical_consultation/${id}/delete`);
```

After I removed that "extra slash", it work correctly.